# Excel SUMPRODUCT treat empty cells of first array as having value 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with the inventory for dungeons and dragons with each row being an item. There is an "amount" column and a "weight per unit" column. What I need to do is calculate the total weight of all items without introducing new columns while treating empty cells in the first array as having the value 1. Example:

| Item | Amount | Unit | Weight per Unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Metal chain | 3 | meters | 2 |
| Skull |  |  | 0.1 |
| Beef Jerky | 4 | bags |  |
| Pen |  |  |  |
| Sealed box |  |  | 5 |

My expected total weight is `(3 × 2) + (1 × 0.1) + (4 × 0) + (1 × 0) + (1 × 5) = 11.1`. Using `SUMPRODUCT(B2:B6;D2:D6)` results in 6 because it treats empty cells as 0, so `(3 × 2) + (0 × 0.1) + (4 × 0) + (0 × 0) + (0 × 5) = 6`

How can I modify the `B2:B6` range so that empty cells are treated as 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to enter a 1 into all the empty cells in B, but you can also use

`=SUMPRODUCT((ISBLANK(B2:B6)+(B2:B6)),D2:D6)`

[image]

To replace blank cells with a value 1, do the following:

- select B2:B6
- open the Go To dialog with F5 or Ctrl G
- click Special
- Tick Blanks
- click OK

Now all blank cells are selected. With that selection intact, type a 1. Then hold down the Ctrl key and hit Enter.

Now all previously empty cells have the value 1 and your original Sumproduct also works.